# How to count multiple total number of different types in one column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I write a query to list the total number of objects for each object type in ascending order of the number of types?

```
Object  |  Type 
-------   ------
1         metal
2         wood
3         metal
4         paper
5         paper
6         wood
7         wood
8         metal
9         plastic
10        wood
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select `type`, count(*) as type_count
from your_table
group by `type`
order by count(*) asc
```

Comment: What is type_count?

Comment: @SiennaAnderson `AS type_count` is an alias.

Comment: @SiennaAnderson: It is the column header for the counts